# getting web data in flash builder mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, beautifulsoup, flash-builder

I'm making the change from Python to flash builder 4.6 as it seems easier for mobile applications.

My question is this, in Python I would use beautiful soup to get the source code of a web page, but after days of google typing the same question in a million ways i cant seem to find an alternative in flash builder.

Is there a way? I want to save the source of a web page to a string and extract bits from it based on search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there are some scraping libraries for AS3.
But anyway you can get the web page data by using HTTPService.

ActionScript

```
private function btnClick(): void{

    hts.url="http://www.foobar.com/foo";
    hts.send();

    // if you want to pass parameters, use below.
    //hts.send({
    //  "id": "abcde",
    //  "pages": "2"
    //});
}

protected function hts_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
    trace(hts.lastResult.toString());
}
```

MXML

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:HTTPService id="hts" method="GET" resultFormat="text" result="hts_resultHandler(event)"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button x="20" y="20" label="Get data" click="btnClick()"/>
```

Comment: brilliant thats just about perfect for me, i will have a go and let you know how i get on.

Comment: I have given it a try and after getting rid of a few errors im getting another one. TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
4.6\DSFRS\src\views\DSFRSHomeView.mxml:45]
 at views::DSFRSHomeView/___DSFRSHomeView_Button3_click()
It seems to point to my    protected function onButton3Clicked():void
   {
   hts.url="http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35";
   hts.send();
    hts.send({"id": "CollapsiblePanel1"});
    trace(hts.lastResult.toString());
   }

Comment: sorry.. that's a mess. I have protected function onButton3Clicked():void that the error seems to point to. I'm not sure what the problem is, although I have changed to from the event in your code, to the one with an event:MouseEvent and they all give errors... sorry i know its a dumb question but i cant get my noggin around it @Yasuyuki Uno

Comment: @RaifJackson sorry too late my response. I tested your url and it returned web page html data. Of course you should parse the data yourself.